# How to click the Spotify Play button with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spotify

Hay,
I try to click the Spotify Play button with Python
[image]
[image]

```
browser.find_element('<button class="btn btn-green false">PLAY</button>').click()
```

What is the correct code line to click required button?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to frame your questions better

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. Please don't post screenshots in place of HTML/code.  Lastly, this is a violation of Spotify's TOS; you should use their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to update your code as

```
browser.find_element('xpath', '//button[.="PLAY"]').click()
```

Note that you should pass **2 arguments** to `find_element` method:

- *locator strategy*, e.g. *xpath*, *css*, etc
- *locator value*

P.S. Also add `browser.maximize_window()` to the beginning of script to set browser *fullscreen* mode (DOM might differs due to different browser window size)

Comment: they give me in the console this error message: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @Maltee , try to `import time` and add `time.sleep(5)` before that line. Does it work now?

Comment: @Maltee , check if `print(len(browser.find_elements('xpath', '//button[.="PLAY"]')))` returns `1`

Comment: yes that works in a special way? it gives me back the number 3

Comment: @Maltee this means that there are more than 1 PLAY button in DOM. Try more specific locator as `browser.find_element('xpath', '//button[contains(@class, "btn-green") and .= "PLAY"]').click()`

Comment: no that dont work too it give me back the same error again: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: oh ok i tryed it with print and this code and it gives me back 2 do you have a idear to make it more specific so it just find 1?

Comment: @Maltee how about `browser.find_element('xpath', '//header[@class="TrackListHeader"]//button[contains(@class, "btn-green") and .= "PLAY"]').click()`? Also make sure that you did `browser.maximize_window()` at the very beggining of script

Comment: dosnt work but when i put it in print it gives me the number 2 again but this time no error

Comment: oh, i missed that i make the screen full size now it worke thank you very much you saved my live <3

Comment: @Maltee , glad to hear) You can accept the answer now if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: year i did thank you for your time and your quick answears :)

Comment: What class is the `browser` from? Or what in particular is `browser`? Looking for a similar solution but don't know where `browser` comes from.

Comment: @developer01 `browser` is an instance of `WebDriver`